# How to append JSON data in table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, css

im trying to read this json using jquery

```
{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "srNo":1,
         "name":"first",
         "amount":1000
      },
      {  
         "srNo":2,
         "name":"second",
         "amount":1600
      }
   ],
   "fullname":"manav",
   "lastname":"kumar"
}
```

this is what i have tried till now

```
$.each(response,function(i,v){
    console.log(v.name);
});
```

if possible please share some demo.
i want to append items in table and rest display in above table

Comment: Is `response` the whole object or just the `items` array?

Comment: You want to loop through `items` property in response?

Comment: What is the question? What is wrong with the code you have? What are you trying to do?

Comment: whole object in seperate fields

Comment: @palaѕн yes but also want to read the name fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I assume that this is ajax post response

following the xDreamCoding answer you can get items array

modifying little.

```
    var newresp = JSON.parse(response);
    //to get names
    console.log(newresp.fullname);
    console.log(newresp.lastname);
    //to get items array
   newresp.items.forEach((e,i) => {
   console.log(e.name)
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
JSON.parse(respone).items.forEach((e,i) => {console.log(e.name)});
```

Comment: Hey thanks this is working but how do get the name fields fullname and lastname thing

Answer (score 1):

To read the `name` fields inside `items` property, you can simply do:

```
$.each(response.items, function(i, v) {
    console.log(v.name);
});
```

Assuming your response is like:

```js
var response = {
  "items": [{
    "srNo": 1,
    "name": "first",
    "amount": 1000
  }, {
    "srNo": 2,
    "name": "second",
    "amount": 1600
  }],
  "fullname": "manav",
  "lastname": "kumar"
}

$.each(response.items, function(i, v) {
  console.log(v.name);
});

// To access fullname & lastname you can use
console.log(response.fullname);
console.log(response.lastname);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hey @palash thanks bhai its working but i also want fullname and lastname